# How to efficiently replace ranges with their median in a dataframe

Tags: r, range

Suppose I have a dataframe named `score.master` that looks like this:

```
school    perc.prof    num.tested
  A           8            482
  B          6-9           34
  C         40-49          49
  D          GE50          81
  E         80-89          26
```

Here, school A's percent proficient is 8%, and the number of students tested is 482. However, suppose that when `num.tested` falls below a certain number (in this case arbitrarily 100), data suppression is introduced. In most cases, ranges of `perc.prof` are given but in other cases a value such as "GE50" is given, indicating greater than or equal to 50.

My question is, in a much larger dataset, what is the best way to replace a range with its median? So for example I want the final dataset to look like this:

```
    school    perc.prof    num.tested
      A           8            482
      B           8            34
      C           44           49
      D           75           81
      E           85           26
```

I know this can be done manually like this:

```
score.master$perc.prof[score.master$perc.prof == "6-9"] <- round(median(6:9), 0)
```

But the actual dataset has many more range combinations. One way I thought of selecting the correct values is by length; all provided values are 1-2 characters long (no more than 99 percent proficient) whereas the range values are 3 or more characters long.

Comment: The second part of your question on imputing data is a stats method question, so it's off-topic on SO but a good fit for [stats.se]. Maybe remove that part of this post from here, and post as its own question on CV

Comment: Done, thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: How do you plan on marking off which groups to impute? In this example, you'd expect to have imputed values for all but school A? And then what do you expect to have for school D?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use stringr::str_split() to get the lower and upper bound, then calculate the median. The "GE50" and similar are not generalizable to this, and you could use ifelse() to handle special cases.

```
df <- data.frame(perc.prof = c('8', '6-9', '40-49', 'GE50', '80-89'))
df$lower.upper <- sapply(stringr::str_split(df$perc.prof, '-'), as.integer)
df$perc.prof.median <- sapply(df$lower.upper, median)
df$lower.upper <- NULL

> df
perc.prof perc.prof.median
1         8              8.0
2       6-9              7.5
3     40-49             44.5
4      GE50               NA
5     80-89             84.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tidyverse approach. First I replace "GE50" with it's expected output, then use `tidyr::separate` to split perc.prof where possible. Last step either uses the given perc.prof if large school, or uses the median for small schools.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(perc.prof = if_else(perc.prof == "GE50", "75", perc.prof)) %>%
  separate(perc.prof, c("low", "high"), remove = F, convert = T) %>% 
  mutate(perc.prof.adj = if_else(num.tested > 100, 
                                 as.numeric(perc.prof),
                                 rowSums(select(., low, high), na.rm = T)/2)
  )

  school perc.prof low high num.tested perc.prof.adj
1      A         8   8   NA        482           8.0
2      B       6-9   6    9         34           7.5
3      C     40-49  40   49         49          44.5
4      D        75  75   NA         81          37.5
5      E     80-89  80   89         26          84.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following to convert your ranges with the median. However, I did not handle the "GExx" or "LExx" situations since it's not well defined enough.

Note that you would need the `stringr` package for my solution.

```
score.master$perc.prof <- sapply(score.master$perc.prof, function(x){
  sep <- stringr::str_locate(x, "-")[, 1]
  if(is.na(sep)) {
    x
  } else {
    as.character(round(median(as.integer(stringr::str_sub(x, c(1L, sep+1), c(sep-1, -1L))))))
  }
})
```